# Word add in: how to activate task pane by click on hyperlink in document

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I develop a word add in using the javascript Word API. I would like to know how I can show some content in the task pane when the user clicks a hyperlink in the document. Is that possible from hyperlinks or perhaps by some other means?

1) User click hyperlink in document 
2) I capture that event (by some unknown means) and something happens in the taskpane, e.g. write the text "you clicked my friend" in the taskpane

Comment: Do you really mean show content, or activate a custom task pane? And is this Office-JS or some other kind of add-in (COM)?

Comment: The task pane is active. I am just trying to find a way by which something happens in the task pane when the user clicks in the documents somewhere

Comment: see https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33088858-no-events-for-standard-operations-like-document-cl